# Do Javascript variables get "optimized away" when debugging React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having difficulty debugging a React JS application.  Both in Visual Studio Code and in the browser debugging tools.  I will come a function and variables I just declared show up as undefined.  Or values I set will show up as empty even though I know they are not (and they work properly after I set them).  I see this debugging both Chrome and Windows Edge.

Is there some kind of hidden switch or flag for optimization that happens with JavaScript/ReactJS that I can turn off with some somewhere?

I use `npm run dev` to start the app, I thought that would prevent this but it does not

For example consider this bit of real code I'm dealing with (I've prefixed it with line numbers)

```
 1:  } else if (id === 'fn2') {
 2:   const LOOP_COUNT = 1;
 3:   const depthMap = JSON.parse(data.results);
 4:     if (depthMapIndexRef.current < LOOP_COUNT) {
 5:       depthMapCalibratedRef.current = depthMapCalibratedRef.current.add(tf.util.flatten(depthMap));
    depthMapIndexRef.current++;
 6:       if (depthMapIndexRef.current === LOOP_COUNT) {
 7:         depthMapCalibratedRef.current = depthMapCalibratedRef.current.div(LOOP_COUNT);
 8:       }
 9:     if (depthMapIndexRef.current >= LOOP_COUNT) {        
10:       pcdRef.current = tf.sub(tf.util.flatten(depthMap), depthMapCalibratedRef.current).dataSync();
11:     const gelImage = new Image();
```

I have had plenty of times in the debugger where:

- I get to line 7 and the value `LOOP_COUNT` shows up as *undefined* in the watch window.  Even though I literally just defined it a few lines above
- At line 11, `pcdRef.current` is either *undefined* or an empty `Float32Array`, even though I know it has a value -- and its UI shows up properly after hit "continue".
- I insert a dummy assignment after line 11 (e.g. `const val = pcdRef.current`) and the debugger literally skips over it the next time I debug the app.

I've tried stopping the app, running npm run dev again for each debugging session.  I've tried using Incognito windows, disabling all extensions and clearing out my browser cache.

I've heard about something called "hoisting" but these variable names are not used anywhere else

Is there a way to "turn off" all optimizations here?  Or is my problem something else?

Comment: No, JS won't optimise a var, unless it goes out of scope, from what I know.   But it could be maybe your JS & Map files are out of sync.  Try switch disable cache checkbox on inside the network tab of the developer tools, and reload page.

Comment: It's probably just weirdness with the Chrome inspector. When you're on a breakpoint, try clicking on the scope above the current one and see if the variable is defined there. Or do something silly like assign `window.LOOP_COUNT = LOOP_COUNT` in the code to make it global and accessible. Sometimes the Chrome inspector is weird in how it makes variable scopes available

Comment: Is there any transpilation or minification step in your toolchain?

Comment: I was on a Teams call with someone who knows this code lot better than me.  (I don't know it or React JS).  Turns out the code in question was inside of a `useEffect` handler and worked fine util I began to use a pre-existing variable declared like this:  `const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = useState(true);`.  I was told it might not have loaded and instead of using it directly, I needed to add this  `firstLoadRef.current = firstLoad;` and then use `firstLoadRef` instead.  Once I did that it worked normally.   I clearly don't understand debugging JavaScript any more than I understand JavaScript.